# Does not imply arrow in \xymatrix?

Tags: math-mode, xy-pic

I am wondering how to make a does not imply arrow when using `\xymatrix`. I have a square diagram with two implications (arrows) on three edges only and one arrow on the fourth edge. One of the arrows should be a "does not imply Rightarrow" on these three edges with two arrows. Thanks for your help.

Here is the latex code I have:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{gathered}
    \quad
    \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@C=4.5em@R=4.5em{ A
      \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d]_-{(3)} \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & B  
      \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{\, \backslash \,}[l]^{} 
      \\
      C          \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]  \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}|{}[u]_-{\;\;(4)}   & D 
      \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l] \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_{\;(5)} }
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Your code snippet in its current form is hardly readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have edited my code the way you said. Hope it is more readable now.

Comment: So you want to draw arrows like `$\not\Rightarrow$`? What's wrong with the arrow from `B` to `A`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have arrows like $\not\Rightarrow$. Mine doesn't quite like $\not\Rightarrow$.

Comment: I have managed to get the diagram I wanted. Thanks again. I have one more question about this diagram. How can I increase the gap between the arrows and the labels? \begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\quad
    \SelectTips{cm}{} \xymatrix@C=4.5em@R=4.5em{ \ac
   \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[d] _-{(3)}\ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{(1)}  & \arc   
        \ar@<1ex>@{=>}|{{\object@{/}}}[l]^-{(2)}         \\
     \sac         \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[r]^-{\;(6)} \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u] |{\object@{/}}|{}_-{\;(4)}   & \sacc 
 \ar@<1ex>@{=>}[l]^-{?} \ar@<-1ex>@{=>}[u]_{\;(5)} }
 \end{gathered}
 \end{equation*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@1{
  A \ar@{=>}[r] |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{/}}|{} & B 
}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kevin C! Yes, I was trying to get a result like this. The problem with mine was that my tilted line does not go through the arrow, it splits the arrow with a space. I am going to try your code now.

Comment: @EileenDavid82 Instead of posting a “Thank you” comment (or, *in addition* to posting a thank you comment), you should thank Kevin C by upvoting the answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). This is part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).